# How to update shared Layout in MVC without sending Data again and again from each view via model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to ASP.net and hence facing a simple problem, I have a shared layout for my different views, That shared layout is being used by many views. 
The shared layout contains a side bar consisting of categories and top navbar. In the current scenario, Whenever I return a view from controller which uses the shared layout, I have to send the data in model or ViewBag to be used by shared layout for its sidebar and other components. Is there any way that shared layout gets the data automatically from model and I don't need to send the data again and again for the components of Shared Layout via model.
I know my question is a bit silly but any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `PartialView` in which you will render the top navbar and sidebar. Than you will call `@Html.Action()` in your layout page that will render this partialview.

**Layout Page**

```
@Html.Action("SideBarPartial", "Home")
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SideBarPartial()
{

//If sidebar is dynamic return data from this controller and pass it to partialview
return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: If you also give a practical example, that will be highly appreciated.